# How can I copy Installation files from one system to another?

Tags: apt, software-installation, kubuntu, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have Ubuntu 20 installed on my new laptop, I have Ubuntu 18.04 on the old one. Is there a way I can just copy `mysql-server` and `mysql-workbench` from the old to the new system without having to run

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

Especially as these versions I used on the old system are no longer available from apt. And the above code doesn't even work anymore! Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu has two different streams of products, main release are *yy.mm* format, eg. the 18.04 you mention, but they also have *snap* only releases like Ubuntu Core 20 (which you may mean with your Ubuntu 20 mention; there is no Ubuntu 20 though, and 20.04 is a different system to the closest Ubuntu Core 20 which maybe assumed with non-existent references of Ubuntu 20).   Please be specific & clarify, as Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS are different systems  (the commands you mention would not be expected to work in Ubuntu Core 20 as you use `snap install`)

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem.  I'm not sure what you are proposing is a good solution to whatever problem you are having.  I suggest that you rewrite the question and ask about the actual problem that you face. Your question doesn't really identify what you're really trying to do and the issues you are experiencing.  We can help you better if you document your real issue.  Do you believe you need a specific version of software?  Why?  Trying to use versions of software that are different from what's available in repos is a recipe for a broken package management system.

Comment: I'm in agreement with Nmath here. Copying wholesale is a recipe for disaster. Are you just trying to maintain specific versions of MySQL on newer installations of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying all the files, which as Matigo said in a comment, is a recipe for disaster.

---

Doing this won't let the system know that you installed it, kind of like using `make install` instead of `checkinstall`, which makes it so you can manage the package as if it was from APT.

At this point, your best bet is to download an archived version.
A quick search on google showed an archive of versions from the mysql website:
Access it [Here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/).